# Функция поделиться текст + аудио

Tags: java, android

Друзья, такой вопрос, хотел сделать функцию поделиться через `Intent`, чтобы выходил текст + mp3 файл, сделал, только вот неувязочка, в Telegram все нормально выводится, а вот например в Whats App выводится только аудио файл без текста, как эту проблему решить, может кто, сталкивался с этим?

Читал в инете, говорят это связано только с Whats App, может можно как то в Whats App отправить и текст и аудио вместе?

Вот мой код:

```
String data = "Мой текст";
String sharePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "audiofile.mp3";
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider", new File(sharePath));
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/mp3");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, getString(R.string.share_audio)));
```

Пробовал также такой код:

```
String data = "Мой текст";
String sharePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "fileName.mp3";
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider", new File(sharePath));
Intent shareText = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Intent shareAudio = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareAudio.setType("audio/mp3");
shareAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareAudio.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareText.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);
shareText.setType("text/plain");
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareText, getString(R.string.share));
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { shareAudio });
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Но также не так, как надо работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
```

С текстом попробуй так

Comment: Так мне не только же текст нужно вытащить, в этом проблем не было б. Мне нужно и текст и аудио вместе. Мой код работает в Telegram, но не работает в Whats App

Comment: Попробуй `audio/mp3` заменить сначала на `audio/*`  если не сработает то на `*/*`